# Replace <p> tags with space

Tags: php, html

I have a string containing a load of mark-up, including `<p>` tags, some of which include class names and other attributes

```
...<span><strong><p class="pp">Text.</p></strong><p class="ppp">More Text.</p><spa...
```

I want to strip all mark-up and have the `<p>` classes be replaced with a space character. When I use `strip_tags()` by itself, then my output is

```
Text.MoreText.
```

I want

```
Text. MoreText.
```

I was considering using `striptags($string, '<p>')` to leave the `<p>` tags, but I can't find any solutions other than using a regexp to then 'strip' the `<p>` tags and replace the closing `</p>` tag with a space instead. I believe this is very error prone.

Comment: Why don't you use regexp? That's a much nicer solution. And what I guess you want to do is just replace the tag to a space but not blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use `</p>` to get your desired result:

```
$string = strip_tags(str_replace('</p>', ' ', $string));
```

Comment: Ah, so simple! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution, after having used `striptags`:

```
echo str_replace('.','. ','Text.MoreText.');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using regex is the best and most tidy solution, just try the below:

```
$string = $string.replace(/<\/p\s*>/, ' ').replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gm, '');
```

1. replace the `</p>` tag, leaving a blank to make a gap;
2. strip all tags.

> Note: using regex is more flexible and can make more exact replacement on some special cases;

Think about `</p >` with a blank after the `p` character? Regex is more useful and easier than you think.